# Hibernate Transaction Demarcation in a non Web application

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I am new to Hibernate and I have some questions about transaction demarcations (I have already searched in Stack Overflow, the Hibernate Documentation.., but I haven't found the answer).

- First I generate the Hibernate Beans and DAOS with the Maven Hibernate Tools Plugin.
- After the generation process, I include my database access jar to my Java project.

Simple queries work fine, but when I execute complex queries with multiple joins, collections are not fetched (lazy fetching) and when I try to call the corresponding

get method to retrieve data, I get an lazy Initialization Exception since my session context is: thread and the session has been closed with the transaction commit.

I need the session to live longer in order to fetch collections explicitly with
a get method.

My hibernate cfg is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
     <property   name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
     <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 /mydatabase</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
      <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    </session-factory>
```

In this case is it necessary to use JTA transactions (I don't use a Web Server) or is it possible to achieve longer sessions not attached to the transactions scope (JDBC) without initializing explicitly the lazy collection?

Comment: Given the fact you answered your own question twice, you should read the Stackoverflow FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the hibernate tools code templates (ftl files) to generate custom DAOs and Beans.

With the Maven Hibernate Tools Plugin, I generate my database access layer.

Would it be reasonable to add to the Hibenate Beans, a method to reattach a detached object to a new Hibernate session? something like:

s.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

r.lock(p, LockMode.NONE);

once data would be retrieved by the getter method the transaction would be commited and the session would be closed. With this strategy I think the lazy initialization problem would be avoided.

Though I'm not sure if there would be any problems in multithread or multiprocess cases.

Thank you.